# Given positive definite $X$, how to generate Hermitian $H$ such that $X\geq H\geq -X$

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, programming, hermitian-matrices

For simulation purpose I need to generate $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $H$ many times. However, all $H$ must satisfy the following inequalities:
$$X\geq H\geq-X,$$

where $X$ is known $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and $X\geq H$ means that $X-H$ is positive semidefinite.

Current method on Matlab:

1. Find largest eigenvalue of $X$, lets call it $\lambda$.
2. Generate random diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal elements being between $-\lambda$ and $\lambda$ .
3. Set $H=VDV^*$, where $V$ is some unitary matrix.

   ```
    beta=2;
    alpha=10;
    for i=1:10
        T=2.*rand(10,10)-1*ones(10,10)+i*(2.*rand(10,10) -1*ones(10,10));   
        [U,S,V]=svd(T);                                                     
        rX=cosd(alpha).*((beta-1/beta).*rand(10,1)+1/beta);                 
        Ah=U*diag(rX)*U';                                                   
        X=Ah*tand(alpha);      

        rH=(2).*rand(10,1)-1;                                  
        H=sqrt(X)*U*diag(rH)*U'*sqrt(X);       

        [eig(X-H) eig(H+X)]                                                
     end
   ```

Generated $H$ doesn't satisfy above inequalities. I don't understand where I am doing mistake, please help me to understand.

Comment: Why not take H=0? or H=X? or H=-X?

Comment: You can't choose $V$ at random.  Instead, use the same $V$ from the diagonalisation of $X$.

Comment: To see what went wrong with random $V$, as an example let $X=\operatorname{diag}(1,10^{-10})$ and let $V$ interchange the two standard basis vectors.  Then your $H$ is $\operatorname{diag}(10^{-10}u_1, u_2)$ for $u_i\sim U[-1,1]$ so the $(2,2)$-entry of $X-H$ is very likely to be negative.

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon because I need many different $H$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all eigenvalues of $H$ lie between $\lambda_\max(X)$ and $-\lambda_\max(X)$ is only a necessary condition for $-X\le H\le X$. It is not a sufficient condition. Consider $X=\operatorname{diag}(3,1)$ and $H=2I$ for instance.

One way to generate $H$ is to use the fact that $-X\le H\le X$ if and only if $-I\le X^{-1/2}HX^{-1/2}\le I$. So, if $U$ is a random unitary matrix, $D$ is a random real diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries lie inside the interval $[-1,1]$, then $H=X^{1/2}UDU^\ast X^{1/2}$ will be a Hermitian matrix that lies between $-X$ and $X$ in the positive semidefinite partial ordering.

Comment: I have modified the code, and set the $H$ according to your answer. But I get eig(X-H) and eig(X+H) complex numbers.

Comment: @Lee The matrix square root of $X$ is `sqrtm(X)`, not `sqrt(X)`.